# Space buttons out evenly (horizontal)

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to space some buttons out across the display and have them be an equal distance apart.

Here's my view xml at the moment http://pastebin.com/DvURNWn3

Comment: You could set them with weights and equal margins.

Answer (score 0):

For each button, change this:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

and set parent element's width `fill_parent` or particular width as below :

```
android:layout_width="40dp"
```

It's good practice to set root element to `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`since nested `layout_weight` may throw `Nested weights are bad for performance` warning.

Comment: Doesn't doing layout_width="0dp" make the buttons invisible?

Comment: No it doesn't. It just fills up all the available space. Read about layout_weight more here : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight

Comment: You wrote layout_width in the answer.